# Proof whether $A - B$ is invertible

Tags: matrices

Given $A^2=A$, $2A−B−AB=I$, prove that $A−B$ is invertible.

---

I have got $(I+A)(A-B)$, what is the next step?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you mean $(I+A)(A-B)=I$?

Comment: You have already found $C$ s.t. $C(A-B)=I$. Verify that $C$ also satisfy $(A-B)C=I$.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done:
$$
\begin{align}
2−− &= \\ 
A-AB+A-B &= I \\ 
A^2-AB+A-B &= I \\ 
A(A-B)+(A-B) &= I \\ 
(A+I)(A-B) &= I
\end{align}
$$

Taking $\det$ from both sides and using the [known fact](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product#:%7E:text=det(AB)%3Ddet,the%20product%20of%20the%20determinants.), you get

$$ \det(A-B)\det(A+I)=1 \\ 
\boxed{\det(A-B) \neq 0}, \ \ \det(A+I) \neq 0$$
Hence $A-B$ is [nonsingular](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonsingularMatrix.html) and [invertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix).

Comment: You already have that $A-B$ is invertible at $(A-B)(A+I)=I$. No need to mention determinants.

Comment: @egreg Yes, but I usually prefer ending by stating that the determinant is nonzero :)

Comment: The relation above also tells you the inverse! By the way, your argument is wrong: from $A(A-B)+(A-B)=I$ you get $(A+I)(A-B)=I$.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for spotting that out. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

It's an important fact that

> a square matrix that has a one-sided inverse is invertible

So if you arrive at $(A+I)(A-B)=I$, you're done.

How did you get there? From $2A-B-AB=I$, you can write
$$
A^2+A-B-AB=I
$$
and therefore $(A+I)A-(A+I)B=I$, which yields
$$
(A+I)(A-B)=I
$$
With the previously mentioned fact you're done.

Why is the mentioned fact true? If you consider an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ to define a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ (or whichever base field you are using), then the linear map induced by $A-B$ has a left inverse, which implies it is injective. But as the space is finite dimensional, the map is also surjective and it has a unique two-sided inverse.